# How to disable next button in jquery steps plugin

Tags: meteor, jquery-steps

I am using Jquery Steps plugin version 1.1.0. Can any experts in the forum help on how to disable next button on moving from step1 to step2. I have tried dooing this in function onStepChanged if currentIndex is 1.I am working with Meteor.

```
$theSteps = $('.steps ul').find('.current');
$($theSteps).next('li').addClass('disabled');
$($theSteps).next('li').removeClass('done');
```

Answer (score 1):

this works 
    $('.actions > ul > li:nth-child(2) > a').attr('href','#next');